# Using a unit of minutes in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

How do I change 1 hour to 10 minutes in the query below?

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num
  FROM values
 WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND ip1 = '$ip1'
   AND ip2 = '$ip2'
   AND submissionid = '$submissionid'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

`INTERVAL 10 MINUTE`

Answer (score 1):

just change `INTERVAL 1 HOUR` to `INTERVAL 10 MINUTE`